# Keep view constant within a table that has expanding hidden content

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, scroll

I have some data that's dynamically populating a table.

The table is within a div with an `overflow: scroll` and `height` property set.

The caveat here is that the data populates from the top.

For my specific situation is that when I am scrolling within the `#container` div, you cannot keep track on a specific row of data as it shifts out of the available view space. In reality this data will be much more complex and be populated at random rates (it's actually an aggregation of live chat data).

My aim is to be able to keep the content still while I scroll freely within the table.

The app is already complex so any native CSS ways to facilitate this would be much preferred.

### Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iamyojimbo/HB7LU/12102/

### JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.data = [];

    var c = 0;
    $interval(function(){
        $scope.data.push({value:c});
        c++;
    }, 150);
}
```

### HTML

```
<h1>Data</h1>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div id='container'>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="element in data | orderBy : '-value'">
                    <td>{{element.value}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    height: 295px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div style="height: 200px;overflow-y:scroll;background-color:#ccc;"id='container'>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Index</th>
                    <th>Data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="element in data">
                    <td>{{element}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

script

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.data = [];

    var c = 0;
    $interval(function(){
        $scope.data.unshift(c);
        c++;
        fixScroll();
    }, 500);
    fixScroll();
}

var oldheight = document.getElementById('container').scrollHeight;
function fixScroll(){
    var newheight = document.getElementById('container').scrollHeight;
    var newAddition = newheight - oldheight;
    document.getElementById('container').scrollTop = document.getElementById('container').scrollTop + newAddition;
    oldheight = document.getElementById('container').scrollHeight;
}
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdkha9jk/

You'll prbably want to code some boolean for when the scroll is at the scroll max and min values to not do the adjustment. You'll see what I mean. Otherwise, let it fill up with content, and I think its working as asked.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with a CSS method, but (unless I am completely misunderstanding the problem) the JavaScript should be fairly simple. There should actually be a few ways to do this.

Probably the easiest would be calling "element.scrollIntoView()" on the newly created element.

I modified your fiddle with a working solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12103/

### JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//Added this function to search your table for the last child element and scroll to it.
function scrollToElement() {
  //Get the last element of this table and scroll it to the bottom of its container.
  if (document.getElementById('test').lastElementChild != null) {
    document.getElementById('test').lastElementChild.scrollIntoView(false);
    //false scrolls the bottom to the bottom. true scrolls top to top.
  }   
}

function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.data = [];

    var c = 0;
    $interval(function(){
        $scope.data.push(c);
        c++;

        //Need to wait for Angular to do its thing...
        window.setTimeout(scrollToElement, 0);
    }, 500);
}
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div id='container'>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Index</th>
                    <th>Data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- I added an id to the below element to find it -->
            <tbody id="test">
                <tr ng-repeat="element in data">
                    <td>{{element}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```